# C# WPF set bound checkbox to checked by default

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a checkbox with it's `IsChecked` property bound already.

```
<CheckBox
x:Name="sortChk"
Content="Sort Variables"
HorizontalAlignment="Right"
Margin="10,10,10,5"
IsChecked="{Binding SortVariables}"
/>
```

I need it to be checked by default on form load. I've seen that having the `IsChecked` property set to `true` will achieve this, but I will lose the binding then.

How do I do this? I'm very new to WPF so forgive me if it's an easy solution.

Edit: I have figured out why the below code was not working on form load, and it's because I did not have it in the Default constructor. Moving it there does the trick. I had a feeling it was something trivial (and stupid on my part). Thanks for the help!

```
DataCompareVM dcvm = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath);
dcvm.SortVariables = true;
DataContext = dcvm;
```

Comment: Set `SortVariables` to have a default value of `true` in the backing code?

Comment: You can probably check out any basic MVVM tutorial for this.

Comment: I have the following property definition. I can't seem to figure out how to set it to default true. public bool SortVariables { get; set; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the SortVariables on your DataContext.

In your xaml.cs file, look for code that looks like:

```
this.DataContext = something;
```

and change it to:

```
something.SortVariables = true;
this.DataContext = something;
```

Comment: I have my DataContext like this: DataContext = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath); Should I pass the checkbox through here as well?

Comment: You have two options, then. Either use this in the xaml.cs:

var dc = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath); dc.SortVariables=true; DataContext = dc;

Comment: ...or second option, in the constructor of DataCompareVM set your property. For instance:
public class DataCompareVM {
   public DataCompareVM() {
       SortVariables = true;
   }
}

Comment: I tried the first option right before seeing your post on it, but it sill doesn't change anything. I went and tried your second too, and still no go. I'm at a loss, something is wrong somewhere and I dont know what

Comment: Great, so you went for the second option. By the way, you look really new to WPF and if you don't want to battle with such things as data-binding I can only strongly suggest my book made for you: https://www.amazon.com/dp/1326847996

Answer (score 5):

Set the default value of the source property to `true`:

```
public bool SortVariables { get; set; } = true;
```

Or if you are still using C#5, create a backing field or set the value of the property in the constructor of the class:

```
private bool _sortVariables = true;
public bool SortVariables 
{
    get { return _sortVariables; }
    set { _sortVariables = value; }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried both those. Neither of them work. Something must be wrong somewhere.

Comment: Of course they both work. "Neither of them work" means what exactly? How do you set the DataContext of the Checkbox?

Comment: What I mean is that having tried both those solutions, the checkbox is still unchecked by default. My DataContext looks like this: DataContext = new DataCompareVM(dataset1FullPath, dataset2FullPath); I'm binding some other data. I didnt do anything with the checkbox because it was working. What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess the SortVariables property is defined in the DataCompareVM class? Otherwise the binding won't work.

Comment: Yes it is. Should I move it?

Comment: No. Then it should work provided that the DataContext of the CheckBox isn't something else. It is impossible to say because you haven't posted your full code/markup.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the rescue... I know it shouldnt matter with constructor initialization, but for real world usage it will probably do the trick.

Comment: @grek40: No need to raise any property notifications just to be able to change the default value of a property.

Comment: @mm8 yea, was just at editing the comment... I'm pretty sure he set it to true somewhere else/later, so *surprise* it doesn't work the same way as your example

Comment: I don't set it anywhere else I believe. I'm not sure how to move forward with this now.

Comment: How should anyone else know? I have already told you how to set the default value of the property. I still don't know how you set the DataContext *of the CheckBox* unless you post all of your relevant code.

Comment: See my original post edit for the solution. I knew it was something stupid on my part. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: You might as well set the SortVariables property directly in the DataCompareVM as I suggested. This certainly works.

Comment: Yes I did that. Thanks